# How to sort a string list in scala?

Tags: scala

I have a large list of string in Scala.
What are the available packages to sort 
a very large list very fast in Scala ?
(over 10 billions elements)

Is this better to use Spark RDD for very large list ?

Comment: Depends. Do you have a few dozens gigs of memory? If the list doesn't even fit into the RAM of a single machine, then what's the point of asking about how to sort it?

Answer (score 0):

Right..use of Spark Dataframes is one option